# JBoss application behind apache ajp proxy with subdomain - duplicated context

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss, proxypass, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

In my application, I'm making some standard scenario where Java web app is deployed on JBoss with apache proxy upfront. The webapp is accessible from /esp context so direct url would be (but I've turned off HTTP for Jboss, only AJP):

```
http://1.2.3.4:8080/esp
```

Now, I've created subdomain and tried proxy move through apache root context. So I'd like apache to proxy:

```
https://mysubdomain.domain.com -> ajp -> Jboss /esp context app
```

I believe that I'm missing something obvious with my configuration, cause only root application context is accessible, and rest of url have dulicated context which ends with 404. For example request are proxied like this:

```
https://mysubdomain.domain.com/css/somecss.css -> ajp -> /esp/esp/css/somecss.css
```

Apache configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
        ServerName mysubdomain.domain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
        ServerName mysubdomain.domain.com

        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/esp/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/esp/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mantis>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/esp.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /var/keys/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/keys/server.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Moreover, when I add additional proxies upfront, everything works:

```
        ProxyPass /esp/ ajp://localhost:8009/esp/
        ProxyPassReverse /esp/ ajp://localhost:8009/esp/
```

Except that app is accessible from apache on both context: `/` and `/esp` while I want only root. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had already similar trouble like the one you have here, and finally found my relevant configuration (adapted to the configuration you posted):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/esp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://mysubdomain.domain.com/esp/
ProxyPassReverse / https://mysubdomain.domain.com/esp/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/esp" "/"
```

Initially I had troubles with ProxyPassRevers but also with the cookie path, even perhaps you could need a `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` Directive (in my case I didn't need it).